# Error on accessing SPpring MVC application

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, ubuntu

Hi I deployed a web app on tomcat server on Ubuntu. But I am getting following error on login.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'dbname.User' doesn't exist
```

my Hibernate Config

```
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <mapping class="com.some.Pojo.User"/>
    <mapping class="com.some.Pojo.Location"/>
    <mapping class="com.some.Pojo.Country"/>
    <mapping class="com.some.Pojo.TrainingRequest"/>
    <mapping class="com.some.Pojo.Priority"/>
    <mapping class="com.some.Pojo.Quarter"/>
    <mapping class="com.some.Pojo.Training"/>
    <mapping class="com.some.Pojo.TrainingType"/>
    <mapping class="com.some.Pojo.Product"/>
    <mapping class="com.some.Pojo.Status"/> 
    <mapping class="com.some.Pojo.SortCategory"/>
```

JDBC properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/dbname
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root
jdbc.show_sql=true
```

Servlet-config

```
      <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
    p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <!-- creating single instance of sessionfactory to be available throughout the application -->

<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<beans:property name="configLocation">
    <beans:value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
</beans:property>
<beans:property name="configurationClass">
    <beans:value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</beans:value>
</beans:property>
<beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
    <beans:props>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
    </beans:props>
</beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Am i missing something? I deployed it on Ubuntu with Tomcat server and with Mysql server as DB.

Comment: Show us a mapping for `com.VMWare.Pojo.User`

Comment: @madhead           @ Entity public class User {  @ Id @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO) private int id;   private String username; private int role;   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")   private List<TrainingRequest> trainingRequestList;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be missing something, but doesn't this line point you to the answer:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'dbname.User' doesn't exist

Comment: Yes. That table is not there in DB. But there is a database table "user". User is my POJO class and with  hibernate it accesses DB table user by POJO class name. That is what my understading is. Application work fine on my dev machine. I am not sure if theres specific config for Hibernate with SPring MVC on Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you  please provide your inputs?

Comment: Hi @BahukeSindi  I read your inputs on same kind of error on stack overflow. Could you please provide your thoughts on above?

Comment: Hi I solved the error after lot of debugging and trial and errors. I simply renamed all the databases name with respect to my POJO names. I know it sound little weird to rename all DB after doing schema export with hibernate configuration, but it worked for me as of now. I still think there has to be some way to fix it in right way.